# Correctively Django query datetime for data/object one hour from now

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i am filtering Django query to getting updatetime last one hour from now,  The model has a DateTimeField.

this is for getting all updatetime that update one hour ago, i've tried using datetime.now() - timedelta(hours = 1), and using range(min,max)

**views i am using (generics.ListAPIView):**

models

`updatetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)`

`onehours = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
queryset = TbDevice.objects.filter(updatetime__gte=onehours).order_by('-updatetime')`

this codes should return updatetime from last hour ago, for example at 2 pm  should return only last hour, but actually all data which has same day showed up

i checked by changing value updatetime manually , only data greater than 06:48:00 showed up when recent time at 14:57:00

is there influence both of them ?
different type
[Update time in my DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2O8F.png)
[in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBHSM.png)

`using timezone`
[Using timezone form django.utils the result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6t69.png) 
[with my current time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzLc3.png)

Comment: This is looking fine. Can you post your model and the view where you've implemented this code. Maybe there's something somewhere else

Comment: class TbDevice(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updatetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'device'

views i am using (generics.ListAPIView):

Comment: should have updated the question. This is for everyone, not just for me

Comment: Do you have `USE_TZ=True` in your settings??

Comment: in my settings.py `USE_TZ=True` already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha!!

you're in `Indonesia`(GMT+7). Your DB(using system timezone) and django(using UTC timezone) has 7 hours of time difference.

try your query using timezone aware datetime format.

```
from django.utils import timezone
one_h_ago = timezone.now()-timezone.timedelta(hours=1)
queryset = TbDevice.object.filter(updatetime__gte=one_h_ago)
```

In postman you're getting `"updatetime": "2019-05-28T22:33:00+7:00"` the *T* in the response tells us that you have enabled timezone support. You have `settings.USE_TZ` and `settings.TIME_ZONE` set.

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Happy to help :)

---

**This is for your knowledge**:

From comments I see your model as:

```
class TbDevice(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True) 
    email = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True) 
    createtime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 
    updatetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True) 

    class Meta: 
        managed = False 
        db_table = 'device'
```

for `createtime` and `updatetime` you should be using

```
createtime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updatetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

check [auto_now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) and [auto_now_add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) for more info.

Comment: thanks , actually i've tried using `timezone` but the results same as before, i've updated the question

Comment: @FajrullahSejatiEvat means the suggested answer didn't worked?

Comment: according to your explanation above
i found a clue , when i set the paramater in 2019-05-29 18:53:00 and then data which updatetime gte 2019-05-29 11:53:00  showed up... 

thats mean, updatetime -7 hours from now

Comment: @FajrullahSejatiEvat That sounds like a quick fix, but not the exact solution. How are you saving your `createtime` and `updatetime`? Have you tried what is suggested in the answer (`auto_now` and `auto_now_add`)?

Comment: my models using your suggestion